# Помогите задать переменную окружения

Tags: linux

Необходимо в `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` задать путь с директорий,где хранятся библиотеки.
Пробовал так :

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/"путь к директории"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Все работало,Но при перезагрузки переменная пустая.
Пробовал и дозаписать в `/etc/environment`.Файл после перезаписи выглядит так:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:bin"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/adm/test/testDir"
```

Но библиотеки все равно не видны в директории,и `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` выводит пустую строку.Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в `~/.bashrc`, или `~/.zshenv`, в зависимости от оболочки.

Обращаю внимание, что `~/` - означает каталог текущего пользователя. Т.е. изменения, в переменных окружения, будут видны только текущему пользователю и программам, которые он запускает от своего имени.

Если программа запускается от имени другого пользователя, то редактировать нужно файл: `/home/имя_пользователя/.bashrc`, или `/root/.bashrc`, если запуск производится из окружения пользователя `root`.

Comment: sudo echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/adm/test/testDir">>~/.bashrc ?

Comment: Возможно и так. Я же не знаю, что у вас в `bashrc`. Откройте `~/.bashrc` в любимом текстовом редакторе и посмотрите. Если там уже есть `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, то отредактируйте, если нет, то добавьте.

Comment: Более того, в приведенной вами команде, `sudo` не сработает так, как вы ожидаете. С правами `root` выполнится только `echo`, а вот перенаправление будет сделано от пользователя.

Comment: И наконец, `~/.bashrc` принадлежит текущему пользователю и для его изменения не нужны права `root`.

Comment: Добавил,но все равно не работает.echo печатает ее после перезагрузки,но все равно библиотека не видна приложению

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос: 1. Что печатает `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` после перезагрузки? 2. Как запускаете приложение?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел более простой и более рабочий способ.
Создал в `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` файл с расширением .conf и просто указал путь к библиотекам.Все работает

Comment: Аккуратнее с этим. `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` - это общесистемная настройка. Если в системе будут установлены аналогичные библиотеки (с аналогичными именами), но другой версии, это может привести к проблемам.